# Bootstrap columns do not work properly

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design

Bootstrap rows and columns do not display properly on phones and other small devices.

**Screenshot on mobile device**

[image: Bad rows].

For tablets and bigger displays, this works properly.

**Code**

```
    <div class="col-xs-5 col-sm-1"><i class="fa fa-mobile" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
    <div class="col-xs-7 col-sm-3">ww</div>
    <div class="col-xs-5 col-sm-1"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
    <div class="col-xs-7 col-sm-3">ww</div>
    <div class="col-xs-5 col-sm-1"><i class="fa fa-map-marker" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
    <div class="col-xs-7 col-sm-3">ww</div>
```

I made a temporary fix - I set the same height for these divs. But I don't think that will be always good solution.

**After Temporary fix** (align added on pic below)

[image: Good rows]

How to resolve this problem in **better way**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem stems from your floats not clearing. This is very common in Bootstrap layouts since almost all elements are floated and so they have included a helper class to deal with it.

```
<div class="clearfix">
```

You insert it in between items which would break to a new line in a specific breakpoint. So, in your case, after the first two "ww" divs for your xs breakpoint.

To only have it affect your xs breakpoint we add another Bootstrap helper class:

```
<div class="clearfix visible-xs">
```

More info on these helper classes can be found in the Bootstrap documentation:
[Clearfix](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#helper-classes-clearfix), [Visibility Classes](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities-classes)

Full example here:

```css
i {
  font-size: 30px !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<div class="col-xs-5 col-sm-1"><i class="fa fa-mobile" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-7 col-sm-3">ww</div>
<div class="clearfix visible-xs"></div>

<div class="col-xs-5 col-sm-1"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-7 col-sm-3">ww</div>
<div class="clearfix visible-xs"></div>

<div class="col-xs-5 col-sm-1"><i class="fa fa-map-marker" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-7 col-sm-3">ww</div>
```

Comment: I was previously trying to use clearfix and visible-xs, but in wrong way... Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

To get proper benefit of bootstrap you should enclose each of 12 grid column in a `row` div. For example,

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-5 col-sm-5"><i class="fa fa-map-marker" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
    <div class="col-xs-7 col-sm-7">ww</div>
</div>
```

Comment: col-sm-1 + col-sm-3 dont equal 12. This layout will break under 768px.

Answer (score -1):

You need to wrap each one of those column groups in 12 column rows. Your cols need to add up to 12 in each row for each breakpoint you add a class for. If you dont wrap them each in a row, they will auto wrap after 12 columns - but you need to make sure that the cols you want on the same row always adds up to 12.

ie.

```
<div class="row>
   <div class="col-xs-7 col-sm-9">ww</div>
  <div class="col-xs-5 col-sm-3"><i class="fa fa-mobile" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
</div>
<div class="row>
    <div class="col-xs-7 col-sm-9">ww</div>
    <div class="col-xs-5 col-sm-3"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
</div>
 <div class="row>   
    <div class="col-xs-7 col-sm-3">ww</div>
    <div class="col-xs-5 col-sm-9"><i class="fa fa-map-marker" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
 </div>
```

This would also work with a bit less control of the layout (but you need to define ALL breakpoints - not just small and XS in your classes).

```
<div class="row>
   <div class="col-xs-7 col-sm-9 col-md-9 col-lg-9">ww</div>
  <div class="col-xs-5 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3"><i class="fa fa-mobile" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>

    <div class="col-xs-7 col-sm-9 col-md-9 col-lg-9">ww</div>
    <div class="col-xs-5 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>

    <div class="col-xs-7 col-sm-9 col-md-9 col-lg-9">ww</div>
    <div class="col-xs-5 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3"><i class="fa fa-map-marker" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
 </div>
```